# How to validate json data in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

Am reading file and storing content  in one variable ie `var json`.

suppose variable contains like this

```
var json = {
    "abc":"abc",
    "xyz":"xyz"
}
```

Above variable contains valid json.

If there is an error happen in Json file, is there a way to find out where the error is, e.g. line number and column number?

like this  if it is invalid

```
var json1 = {
"abc":"abc",
"xyz":xyz"
}
```

The error should show like this

```
Parse error on line 3:
...: "abc",    "xyz": xyz"}
----------------------^
```

Comment: *"This is valid json file"* No, that's a valid JavaScript object initializer, within an assignment statement, combined with a `var` statement. No JSON here.

Comment: Actually, it's an *invalid* object initializer: You're missing the `"` after the `xyz` property name.

Comment: Your invalid JSON will give JavaScript error right away with line number, in your console

Answer (score 6):

You don't have any JSON in your question, but if we assume you do:

```
var json = '{ "abc":"abc", "xyz":"xyz" }';
```

All modern browsers support `JSON.parse`, which will throw an exception if the JSON is invalid, so:

```
try {
    var obj = JSON.parse(json);
}
catch (e) {
    // The JSON was invalid, `e` has some further information
}
```

Those won't give you line and column, though. To do that, you may need a parsing script. Before browsers had `JSON.parse` built in, there were scripts like [Crockford's `json2.js`](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/) and [various others listed at the bottom of the JSON.org page](http://json.org/) that may give you line and character info (or can be modified to).

`JSON.parse` example:

```js
var valid = '{ "abc":"abc", "xyz":"xyz" }';
test("valid", valid);

var invalid = '{ "abc", "xyz":xyz }';
test("invalid", invalid);

function test(label, json) {
  try {
    JSON.parse(json);
    snippet.log(label + ": JSON is okay");
  }
  catch (e) {
    snippet.log(label + ": JSON is malformed: " + e.message);
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: am using JSON.parse(json) error also am getting BUT i need where exactly error happened like row number and column num i Don't want to use any json online validate sites

Comment: @shas: I've added a note above about line and column info.

Comment: i had check that one but json2.js having some logic .. Should have to use logic or file itself ..?

Comment: @shas: You'll have to read through to see if it gives you what you need or if you have to add it to the code; or check out the other JavaScript parsers on the linked json.org page.

Comment: Thank its Worked . But having problem.. this try catch method gives Correct Ans in Firefox but other Browsers giving wrong .. how to solve .. help me